# OpenCV multiple USB camera on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I've looked at lots of previous questions related to this, and none have helped.

My setup:

- One of [these](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00VG32EC2)

  - they show up as `/dev/video0` and `/dev/video1`
  - Images are 640 x 480
- Raspberry Pi 3
- Raspbian Jessie
- OpenCV 3.1.0
- Python 2.7

For either one of the cameras I can capture images and display them at a pretty decent rate with minimal latency (and occasional artifacts).

When I try to use both, however, I get *maybe* a 10th the frame rate (although the delay between frames seems to vary wildly with each frame) with all sorts of nasty image artifacts (see below for example) and an intolerable amount of lag.

[image: artifacts]

The problem does **not** seem to be the camera itself or USB bandwidth on the device: when I connect the cameras to my Windows PC, I am able to capture and display at 30 FPS without any visual artifacts and very little lag.

As best I can tell, it must be the Pi hardware, the drivers or OpenCV which is the problem. I don't think it's the Pi hardware.. I would be happy if I could achieve with two cameras half the frame rate I get with one camera (and I don't see why that shouldn't be possible) and no ugly artifacts.

**Does anyone have any suggestions?** I'm ultimately just trying to stream the video from the two cameras from my Pi to my desktop. If there are suggestions that don't involve OpenCV, I'm all ears; I am not trying to do any rendering or manipulation of the images on the Pi, but openCV is the only thing I've found that captures images even reasonably quickly (with one camera, of course).

Just for reference, the simple python script I'm using is this:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import socket
import ctypes
import struct

cap = []
cap.append(cv2.VideoCapture(0))
cap.append(cv2.VideoCapture(1))

#grab a single frame from one camera
def grab(num):
    res, im = cap[num].read()
    return (res,im)

#grab a frame from each camera and stitch them
#side by side
def grabSBS():
    res, imLeft  = grab(1)
    #next line is for pretending I have 2 cameras
    #imRight = imLeft.copy()
    res, imRight = grab(0)
    imSBS = np.concatenate((imLeft, imRight), axis=1)
    return res,imSBS

###For displaying locally instead of streaming
#while(False):
#    res, imLeft = grab(0)
#    imRight = imLeft.copy()
#    imSBS = np.concatenate((imLeft, imRight), axis=1)
#    cv2.imshow("win", imSBS)
#    cv2.waitKey(20)

header_data = ctypes.create_string_buffer(12)

while(True):
    sck = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sck.bind(("10.0.0.XXX", 12321))

    sck.listen(1)

    while(True):
        (client, address) = sck.accept()
        print "Client connected:", address
        try:
            while(True):
            res,im = grabSBS()
            if(res):
                success, coded = cv2.imencode('.jpg', im)
                if (success):
                    height, width, channels = im.shape
                    size = len(coded)
                    struct.pack_into(">i", header_data , 0, width)
                    struct.pack_into(">i", header_data , 4, height)
                    struct.pack_into(">i", header_data , 8, size)
                    client.sendall(header_data .raw)
                    client.sendall(coded.tobytes())
        except Exception as ex:
            print "ERROR:", ex
            client.close()
            sck.close()
            exit()
```

**UPDATE**: I got it working much, much better by adding the following lines of code after initializing the VideoCapture objects:

```
cap[0].set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 15)
cap[1].set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 15)
```

This both lowers the bandwidth required and the openCV workload. I still get those horrible artifacts every few frames, so if anyone has advice on that I'm happy to hear it.

Comment: are the camera images encoded?? what happens if you use the `###For displaying locally instead of streaming` way instead of streaming?

Comment: Encoded at what point? I don't know what form they take when OpenCV retrieves the images from the drivers. VideoCapture.read() returns the image as a Numpy ndarray, which is a raw format. I then use JPEG encoding to reduce size and send them over the network.

As for the "###For displaying locally" bit, when I use that it displays the video on the Pi's display. That code isn't using both cameras, though, just the one camera, and then it duplicates the image to pretend it has two.  The video is very smooth when I use that.

Comment: Some thoughts... I believe there is just a single USB controller that the cameras and network interface must all share - that could be a bottleneck. Also, could you go multi-threaded as the Pi has 4 cores and maybe let one thread do the JPEG encoding, or have two threads and let them do alternate frames? Just a thought.

Comment: i meant encoded from the camera so that the pi has to decode them which might be a bottle neck. pc is probably faster.

Comment: can you try to merge the images (e.g. cooy both to one big image) and encode + stream only a single image? and/or try to resize (smaller) the images before encoding/streaming to get a better idea of where the bottle neck might be?

Comment: @MarkSetchell That wouldn't explain why it's a complete non-issue when I use the cameras on my windows PC. The JPEG encoding is actually not much of a latency problem. Either way, I am planning on working on improving latency once I get it at least working correctly

@Micka I don't know if they're encoded coming from the camera. Is there a way to find out?
Also, I already am stitching the images together and treating it as a single image for encoding and network purposes (that's what the `imSBS = np.concatenate(...)` bit does)

Comment: sorry, Im not so familiar with pythonCV. Please try to downsample before encoding/streaming (if that's better your problem probably is in encoding/streaming). and please try to grab from a single cam and duplicate that image (if that's better your problem probably is in image capturing/bandwith/synchronization/decoding)

Comment: ok you already did tip2 (in the "pretending to have 2 cams" part)? was it better?

Comment: @Micka The streaming is definitely not the problem. Other than the gross artifacts, the whole thing works perfectly fine when I use one duplicated image instead of two distinct images.

Comment: I should have mentioned it own here (see update in my original post), but I've gotten everything to work except I still have the artifacts that show up.. those are the only problem now.

Comment: are you able to try 2 different cams? maybe the linux cam driver gets confused or sth? or maybe try a different viewer (vlc?) with both cams at the same time to check whether there are artifacts too? what happens if you set fps to 1 or 5?

Comment: @Micka Thanks for your input, I found something that seems to work, though I'm not really sure why... at all..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, after spending about 5 hours fighting with it, I seem to have found solutions.

First, apparently OpenCV was trying to capture at 30 FPS even though I wasn't able to pull frames at 30 FPS. I changed the VideoCapture frame rate to 15 FPS and the video became much, much smoother and faster.

```
cap[0].set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 15.0)
cap[1].set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 15.0)
```

That didn't get rid of the artifacts, though. I eventually found that if I do `del(im)` after sending the image over the network, the artifacts completely went away.

Comment: this looks like sending over network is going on asynchrously  and you're changing the bits "while" they're being sent or copied? but that would mean deleting the image before it is sent completely, so probably that isn't the reason or you're just lucky.

Comment: @Micka Interesting thought.. I hadn't considered that it might be going on asynchronously. I was apparently assuming that `sendall()` was a blocking call. Either way, I experienced the artifacts even when I was just displaying the images locally -- not using the network at all. When not using the network, none of the python code is asynchronous, and so there shouldn't be any issues with two threads operating on the same buffer at the same time, unless OpenCV is doing something naughty and continuing to write to the Numpy ndarray after it's handed it over to me.

Comment: the camera might write to a buffer continuously, but normally that shouldnt be the buffer that you access.