# Bandwidth limitations for video capturing on a Raspberry Pi and how to overcome them

Tags: raspberry-pi, video-capture, raspberry-pi4

I'm experimenting with capturing and saving two video streams with USB cameras directly on a Raspberry Pi 4. The cameras appear in `/dev` as `/dev/video0` and `/dev/video2` and both are tested independently to work with a frame rate of 30 fps.

I started both streams simultaneously with the command

```sh
sh -c 'ffmpeg -f v4l2 -r 25 -s 640x480 -i /dev/video2 left.avi & ffmpeg -f v4l2 -r 25 -s 640x48
0 -i /dev/video0 right.avi & wait'
```

I encountered that the frame rate of one camera is ~25fps while the other one shows the following output

```
frame=1 fps=0.2 q=2.9 size=6kB time=00:00:00.04 bitrate=1135.6kbits/s speed=0.00983x
```

One of the videos played as expected, in the other one just a few frames were stored. The same problem occurred when I tried to capture a video using OpenCV's `VideoCapture()` class.

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36521421/opencv-multiple-usb-camera-on-raspberry-pi-3) question and reduced the frame rate to 15 in `ffmpeg` like so

```sh
sh -c 'ffmpeg -f v4l2 -r 15 -s 640x480 -i /dev/video2 left.avi & ffmpeg -f v4l2 -r 15 -s 640x480 -i /dev/video0 right.avi & wait'
```

which didn't change the issue, just by looking at the file sizes of the two captured files we see that they differ extremely

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/code-py$ ls -l
total 520
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 490368 Mar 18 14:05 left.avi
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu   5686 Mar 18 14:05 right.avi
```

and essentially the same happens using OpenCV's `capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 15)`.

In a third step I halved the video size like so

```sh
sh -c 'ffmpeg -f v4l2 -r 30 -s 320x240 -i /dev/video2 left.avi & ffmpeg -f v4l2 -r 30 -s 320x240 -i /dev/video0 right.avi & wait'
```

and it worked! Apparently something in the Raspberry gets overwhelmed by the amount of bytes flowing in, but how do I figure out what it is? All in all 320x240 is a pretty bad resolution and I wonder if it is possible to find the limiting factor and increase it.

**Edit:**

Here is the output of `lsusb -t` with the cameras plugged into the USB 3 port:

```
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 5000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/1p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 3, If 2, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 3, If 3, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 480M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 4, If 3, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 480M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 4, If 2, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 480M
```

Comment: The way you have plugged them into the USB ports could make a difference. Try `lsusb -t` to see speed allocations.

Comment: @MarkSetchell here is the output I get: https://pastebin.com/Yk1hKpRf

Comment: Why `pastebin`? The output belongs in your question. Please click `edit` under your question and add it in. You appear to have plugged both cameras into the slower 480 MHz USB 2 ports rather than the faster 5 GHz USB 3 ports.

Comment: Pastebin because the text is exceeding the comment limit. I've tried both, I also plugged the cameras into the USB 3 ports but the described problem remains the same.

Comment: Maybe you can plug them into the USB 3 ports, re-run the `lsusb -t` and paste the output into your question and check again. If still slow, try unplugging the faster camera leaving the other one *"as-is"* to be sure it's not the cable.

Comment: I did, the output seems identical (the cameras themselves are using USB 2). Both cameras on their own can record videos with 30fps and 640x480

Comment: Your listing shows you have plugged them into the slower USB 2 ports. Plug them into the blue ports adjacent to the Ethernet and they will show up at the top of the listing with 5000M as the speed.

Comment: I guarantee you, they are plugged into the blue USB 3 ports. For testing purpose I just plugged in an USB stick (which has the blue USB 3 port) and this one is showing up with "5000M" when running lsusb -t.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An RGB888 stream of 640x480 data at 30fps takes the following bandwidth:

```
640 * 480 * 3 * 30 * 8    i.e. about 220 Mbits/s
```

And that is almost half the bandwidth of 480 Mbits/s USB 2 so you are not realistically going to be able to run 2 such streams smoothly.

You can check USB bandwidth using the `lsusb -t` command. Here is a memory stick plugged into the USB 2 port - you can see it is allocated 480 Mbits/s:

```
lsusb -t
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 5000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/1p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M   <--- HERE
```

And here is the device plugged into the blue USB 3 port nearer to the Ethernet - allocated 5Gbits/s:

```
lsusb -t
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 5000M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 5000M  <--- HERE
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/1p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
```

**Keywords**: USB 2, USB 3, bandwidth, speed allocation.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, if I plugin in the USB 2 cameras into the USB 3 ports, the data transfer speed of each camera is at max 480 Mbits/s. My expectation would be that the Raspberry Pi would still be able to pick up those 220 Mbits/s data streams from each USB 3 port and process it but apparently this is not the case.

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't know how/why your cameras plugged into the USB 3 ports show up as plugged into the USB 2 ports. What happens if you just attach one camera, and run `lsusb -t` with it successively plugged into each of the 4 ports? Does It ever get to the top of the list on Bus 02 at 5000M like mine?

Comment: No, also just one camera is shown with "480M", I get "5000M" with another device (an USB stick) that has a blue USB 3 port.

Comment: So, regardless of which USB port you plug your camera in, it NEVER appears Bus 02?

Comment: Correct, no matter in which ports I put the cameras, they always appear under Bus 01.Port. The USB stick however appears under Bus 02.Port when plugged into the USB 3 port on the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Are you running Raspbian (Raspberry Pi OS)?

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS on the Pi

Comment: Aha! Maybe that is the difference. Sorry I don't have any other ideas.

Comment: Ok, this is my last idea. Try plugging one camera into a blue USB 3 port and the other into a non-blue USB 2 port. Maybe being on 2 separate controllers will give each camera enough bandwidth!

Comment: Just tried that, same result. Event if I just plug in one camera in the USB 3 port, it appears under Bus 01 Port with 480M. I start to wonder if the limitation is on the USB camera side.

Comment: My money is on it being that Ubuntu is less well tested than Raspbian... I would be inclined to burn a Raspbian image and try it. Please update if/when you get a solution. Good luck!