# Read and process frames from multiple USB cameras using RPI 3b+ and(may) opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, video-capture

I'm working on a little project in which I need to record images from two USB cameras and read and process some from another USB camera. I'm doing all this in a raspberry pi 3b+. the script works fine just processing data from one camera and recording from an additional camera, but when I add a third one it starts going wrong. This is a simple code which records video from 3 inputs:

```
import cv2 

cap1 = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap2 = cv2.VideoCapture(2)
cap3 = cv2.VideoCapture(4)

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G')
out1 = cv2.VideoWriter('video.avi', fourcc, 30, (640,480))
out2 = cv2.VideoWriter('video1.avi', fourcc, 30, (640,480))
out3 = cv2.VideoWriter('video2.avi', fourcc, 30, (640,480))



while True

    ret, frame1 = cap1.read()
    _, frame2 = cap2.read()
    _, frame3 = cap3.read()
    
    if ret
        
        out1.write(frame1)
        out2.write(frame2)
        out3.write(frame3)
```

this is the error I get in a loop, isn't always the same device that is not being read (video0 as here):

```
[ WARN:0] global /tmp/pip-wheel-xjhn4aom/opencv-contrib-python_db9bf2c2b8dd41b592a48d20aac72627/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp (1001) tryIoctl VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video0): select() timeout.
```

it seems to be an v4l issue, I tried to use v4l2 using

`stereo1 = cv2.VideoCapture(0,cv2.CAP_V4L2)`

but it doesn't take any effect, I'm reading images to 640x480 (because I can't change it), so I think resolution isn't the problem. I also tried threading and got same warning and no data from that device. is it any bandwidth issue or something like that with the video reader driver?

I'm using three generic USB cameras (as its named in v4l2 -list devices)

Any suggestions what it might be? Should I use another method for video recording?

**Edit:**  using `lsusb`

```
Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=dwc_otg/1p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/3p, 480M
            |__ Port 1: Dev 6, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=lan78xx, 480M
            |__ Port 2: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
                |__ Port 1: Dev 7, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
                |__ Port 1: Dev 7, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
                |__ Port 2: Dev 8, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
                |__ Port 2: Dev 8, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 5, If 3, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 480M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 5, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 5, If 2, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 480M
```

using `v4l2-ctl --list-devices`

```
GENERAL WEBCAM: GENERAL WEBCAM  (usb-3f980000.usb-1.1.2.1):
    /dev/video2
    /dev/video3

GENERAL WEBCAM: GENERAL WEBCAM  (usb-3f980000.usb-1.1.2.2):
    /dev/video4
    /dev/video5

GENERAL WEBCAM: GENERAL WEBCAM (usb-3f980000.usb-1.2):
    /dev/video0
    /dev/video1
```

sorry for my bad explanation. The camera on dev/video4 and dev/video2 are two cameras on one board, so it uses a hub driver to communicate. this means that these two cameras are connected to one port, and dev/video0 are connected to a different one. I still can read and write video using this onboard cameras at the same time.

Comment: Is there some reason to run all 3 video streams in one process? You will probably be able to use more of your 4 CPU cores by running 3 separate processes? Have you got each camera plugged in its own USB port... rather than using a USB hub? Have you got a good power supply for your Pi - or can you use powered USB hubs?

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I also tried running it in 3 different processes, as I said I also tried running it using threads and it didn't work. I am using a 2.5A power supply for the rpi and it doesn't seem to need more power. I am also powering the cameras from an external source so as not to use power from the rpi. All the USB cameras are connected to a single port without using a powered hub but just bypassing the power pins to an external shared source.

Comment: I don't understand how you can connect 3 cameras to a single port?

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/66720059/2836621 Can you run the suggested `lsusb` commands and paste the output into your question please, not in the comments. Thank you.

Comment: It's quite possible you simply don't have enough USB bandwidth to drive that many streams.  If your cameras are sending YUV data, 640x480x30 at 2 bytes per pixel is 18MB/s.  Two such cameras will saturate a USB 2.0 pipe.  Are you able to select a compressed format from the cameras?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Done, thank you.

Comment: @TimRoberts It looks like the only compression mode my cameras support are MJPG and YUYV, using ´v4l2-ctl --list-formats-ext´ is what i get. I'm using JMPG because YUYV returns very bad video quality to 640x360 resolution, but it seems worst.

Comment: No, you are asking opencv to CONVERT the videos to MJPG.  You haven't done anything to choose a format from the cameras.

Comment: And remember that the Raspberry Pi 3B+ processor is not a huge performer.  You're not going to do much real-time video processing.

Comment: Have you tried reducing the frame rate of capturing? Does it help? `cap1.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 10)`